# Return count from not direct related tables

Tags: mysql

To clarify what I'm asking:
My main goal was how I can retrieve all Manufacturers with a count of entries next to them.

Working with 3 tables {Manufacturers (`wp_manufacturers`), Dealers(`wp_users`), Entries(`wp_posts`)} [plus a fourth, `wp_usermeta`, tied to `wp_users`].

- Manufacturers hold brands like Suzuki Honda etc
- Dealers as the users publishing an Entry that showcase a Car of a manufacturer.
- Entries is the table that holds an entry with the content and the user who published.

The table Dealers has a field that connects every user with the Manufacturer (actually, currently set up through the fourth table).

**What I trying to do is to have for every Manufacturer a count of entries that exist in the Entries table.**

A dealer can be only with one manufacturer. Also, a manufacturer can have multiple dealers.

This is original for a WordPress site that is heavily customized and we would like a direct approach to the database.

Given this data, with 2 Manufacturers and 3 dealers:

```
  Manufacturers           wp_posts
+-----------------+    +-----------------------------------------------+
|id      |name    |    |ID     |post_author    |post_type |post_status |
+-----------------+    +-----------------------------------------------+
|   1    |suzuki  |    | 455   |    13         |  car     | publish    |
|   2    |honda   |    | 689   |    13         |  car     | publish    |
|        |        |    | 1689  |    2          |  car     | publish    |
|        |        |    | 1889  |    13         |  car     | draft      |
|        |        |    | 2090  |    44         |  car     | publish    |
+---^----+--------+    +------------^----------+----------+------------+
    |                           ____|
    |           wp_usermeta    |
    |          +---------+-----v-------------+------------------+
    |          |umeta_id | user_id |meta_key | meta_value       |
    |          +------------------------------------------------+
    |          | 498     |   13     | _manuf  |     1           |
    |          | 709     |   2      | _manuf  |     2           |
    |          | 1029    |   44     | _manuf  |     2           |
    |          |         |          |         |                 |
    |          +------------------------------------------------+
   ++----------------------------------------------^
```

The results I'd like to get are:

```
+-------+----------+--------------+
|  id   |   name   |   count      |
+---------------------------------+
|  1    | suzuki   |     3        |
+---------------------------------+
|  3    | honda    |     2        |
+-------+----------+--------------+
```

I also want to check the `post_status` to only count entries that have been published.

Today I read again my question and I found indeed not clear. The reason I didn't like to write from the start the table original names was not to be confused with the WordPress solution as I would like only the MySQL approach.

Example on the wp site where I use the tables of wp this returns the data but not with 0 when not an entry found in the wp_post(post_type=car) and also not sure this is the optimal way to do this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id, IFNULL(COUNT(id),0),name FROM (
SELECT wp.post_author,wp.post_status,wp.post_type,wu1.meta_value FROM wp_posts wp
  LEFT JOIN (
  wp_users wu
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wu1 ON wu1.user_id=wu.ID
  ) ON wp.post_author=wu.ID 

  WHERE wu1.meta_key='_manuf' AND wp.post_status='publish'  AND wp.post_type='car'
 ) x
 left jOIN manufacturers ma  ON x.meta_value=ma.id

  GROUP BY id
  ;
```

Comment: If there are no entries for a manufacturer, should they be left off the list, of show up with a count of 0?

Comment: @RDFozz Nice Catch IFNULL(count_num,0)  :)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It sound like you've got a  new database with `wp_manufacturers`, `wp_users`, and `wp_posts`, but in responding to Kondybas' answer, you refer back to the `wp_usermeta` table, which you don't include at the top of you question. Are you trying to come up with a better query than the one you show, or is it a query that works with the current database, but won't with the new one? If you're looking to improve the current query, an `EXPLAIN PLAN` would be helpful. Does the current query give you the output you want? Sample input and desired output would also help.

Comment: @RDFozz I have made an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're refactoring the database to optimize it for your actual business needs, you will probably want to make a number of changes. Since we don't see your full data structure, or your full set of business rules, we can't tell you everything that should be changed.

First, I'll refer to the tables by the new names:

- `wp_manufacturers` = `manufacturer`
- `wp_users` = `dealer`
- `wp_posts` = `entry`

That said, you've given us one business rule that would imply a change. Every `dealer` should be tied to one and only one `manufacturer`. So, I would move the manufacturer link from the meta table directly into `dealer`. I'd name the new `dealer` field `manufacturer_id`.

Odds are good I would move all the data from `wp_usermeta` into `dealer`, but not knowing what all is there, I can't say for certain.

I would also probably change the name of the `post_author` field in `entry` to `dealer_id`, to make it more clear that it's the link to the `dealer` table.

So, with that said, your query will greatly resemble what Kondybas provided, with a couple of tweaks:

```
SELECT manu.name as Manufacturer
      ,COUNT(entry.id) as Post_Count
  FROM manufacturer manu
         LEFT JOIN dealer ON (manu.id = dealer.manufacturer_id)
           LEFT JOIN entry ON (    dealer.id = entry.dealer_id
                               AND entry.post_status = 'publish'
                              )
 GROUP BY manu.name
 ORDER BY Manufacturer
;
```

See it in action with a version of your sample data at this [db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jSdjVAT7k7xa4JQNauQ4ji/0)

Output is:

```
 Manufacturer | Post_Count
--------------+------------
   Honda      |       3
   Kia        |       0
   Suzuki     |       2
```

The changes I made to your sample data was:

- Adding a third manufacturer with no posts, so you could see that I properly list them with 0 posts;
- Adding a second post by the third dealer, so the count would match what you expected.

Note that I do *not* count the `entry` marked 'draft', per your note in the question that only items marked 'publish' should be counted. If the actual rule is more complicated, you should be able to modify this to match the actual rule.

Explanation of the query:

- We use a `LEFT JOIN` to connect `dealer` and `entry` to `manufacturer`; this lets us show all manufacturers, even ones with either no connected dealers, or with no dealers who have published posts.
- We include the restriction that we only want to count `entry` rows with a `post_status` of 'publish' in the `LEFT JOIN` criteria. If we listed this in a WHERE clause for the query as a whole, then manufacturers who don't tie to an `entry` would be excluded, since `entry.post_status` would be `NULL` instead of 'publish'.
- Finally, we use `COUNT(entry.id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. If we used `COUNT(*)` we'd get a value of 1 even if a manufacturer had no matched `entry` rows, because we always have at least one row, with the `manufacturer` data. Since every `entry` record will have a non-`NULL` `id`, we'll count that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed explanation. This kind of answers provide crucial info and help us become better.

Answer (score 0):

If your `dealers` are related to the `manufacturers` and `entries` are related to the `dealers` so you have to `JOIN` three tables, then `GROUP` resulting table by `manufacturers` and `COUNT()` all entries grouped together:

```
SELECT w.ID AS manufacturer
     , count( q.ID ) AS counter
  FROM manufacturers AS w
  JOIN dealers       AS z ON z.manuf_ID  = w.ID
  JOIN entries       AS q ON q.dealer_ID = z.ID
 GROUP BY w.ID
 ORDER BY w.ID ASC
;
```

Comment: I have edit the question to include the query I have. Entries(wp_posts has an authored field that this connects to the dealers table (wp_users) as a meta field

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is better than `COUNT(ID)` unless you need to check `ID` for NULL.

Comment: The is no provision for a 0 count.